# Can records be inserted while the SELECT statement is executing in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency

I have a query that does something like this --

```
SELECT localtimestamp, x, y, z 
FROM table1 
WHERE updated_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 minute';
```

`updated_at` is defined to be set to the `current_timestamp` by default (in this case, I've verified that `localtimestamp` and `current_timestamp` are the same on the DB server).

Is it possible for this query to return records `where updated_at > localtimestamp` (the first field returned by the query)? In other words, can records be inserted into the table while the query is executing?

There are no explicit locks being acquired or transactions in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other inserts are allowed to happen, but your query won't see them.

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-transaction.html) on isolation levels:

> A statement can only see rows committed before it began. This is the default.